# 'put on hold' or 'kept on hold'

Tags: phrases

I was trying to write a formal email to my manager stating that the change controls are put on hold. For 'put on hold', I meant that the change controls are on 'hold' status and are no more processed.

So what is the correct usage - 'Put on hold' or 'kept on hold'.

Comment: In this typical context of notifying someone, I'd prefer this - *...the change controls are being held for [the reason].*

Comment: My suggestion? Use neither _keep_ nor _put_: ***The change controls are on hold.***

Comment: @MaulikV - I don't like that suggestion one bit. "On hold" is somewhat idiomatic, and changing "are on hold" to "are being held" makes it sound like you're clasping them in your hand or something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both references differ:

Saying things are put on hold is different than kept on hold. Keeping something on hold, means that sometime has passed and it's still on hold, while put refers to the action of going to put it on hold.

Answer (score 5):

**"Put on hold"** means the action of putting on hold and it refers to an *instance of time* when "that thing" was put on hold.

e.g.

> Moderator has **put the question on hold** for its fuzzy context.

**"Kept on hold"** refers to the *duration of time* after it was "put on hold" to the time it will be taken "out of hold"

e.g.

> Moderator is **keeping the question on hold** *until* the context is made more clear.

Comment: [The moderator]